# Polymorphic assosiation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphic-associations

I have models Comment and Topic. I want to create another model called Storage.
So now I have this in `Storage.rb`:

```
  with_options inverse_of: :storage do
    has_many :comments, as: :editable
    has_many :topics, as: :editable
  end
```

Migration:

```
  t.references :editable, polymorphic: true
  t.timestamps
```

The storages table:

```
    t.string "editable_type", null: false
    t.bigint "editable_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["editable_type", "editable_id"], name: "index_storages_on_editable_type_and_editable_id"
```

`Comment.rb`:

```
belongs_to :editable, polymorphic: true, optional: true
```

`Topic.rb`:

```
belongs_to :editable, polymorphic: true, optional: true
```

The whole reason I am trying to use polymorphic assosiation is that I supposedly can get the Comment object from Storage. Like if Comment somehow gets into Storage, I should be able to do something lik `Storage.particular_comment.user_id` and get the id of the user, who wrote this comment.

However, I'm unable to do so. I suppouse that there is a mistake somewhere in my assosications, but I just don't see/understand it. Thanks!

Comment: how are you querying for the comment? `Storage.where(editable: Comment.find_by(user_id: 1))` should get you the comment in the storage table. From there, without knowing more of the associations, you could get the userid

Comment: It might be helpful to explain the overall goal of this Storage model. Based on what you've written it seems that it might be superfluous and could be achieved with the two models you have right now.

Comment: @sam the goal of the `Storage` model was to simply has an instance of `Comment` or `Topic`, so you can reach it anytime you need.

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery this is a quite long query, the goal was to make everything short and effective. I was able to achieve that in my answer below

Comment: @Giasod, sorry, I thought you were wanting to query, not already having the correct instance of Storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. Turns out, my main mistake was that I didn't understand the associations correctly. The correct way to do this with minimum query and efforts is the following:

`Storage.rb`:

```
  belongs_to :editable, optional: true, inverse_of: :storages, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :topic, inverse_of: :storages, optional: true
  belongs_to :comment, inverse_of: :storages, optional: true
```

`Comment.rb` and `Topic.rb`:

`has_many :storages, as: :editable, inverse_of: :comment, dependent: :nullify`

`has_many :storages, as: :editable, inverse_of: :topic, dependent: :nullify`

the storage table remain the same.

The above-mentioned associations allowed to achieve the following result:

```
> c = Comment.last
> st = Storage.create!(:editable => c)
> st
=> #<Storage:0x007fb45d8fcb40> {
             id: 1,
  editable_type: "Comment",
    editable_id: 9,
     created_at: Thu, 11 Feb 2021 05:45:10 EST -05:00,
     updated_at: Thu, 11 Feb 2021 05:45:10 EST -05:00
```

Now it is very easy to get any information needed without long and complex queries:

```
> st.editable
=> #<Comment:0x0055ddca8eddb8> {
          id: 9,
     user_id: 392,
    topic_id: 1183,
     content: "test",
  created_at: Wed, 10 Feb 2021 11:17:42 EST -05:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 10 Feb 2021 11:17:42 EST -05:00
> st.editable.user_id
=> 392
> st.editable.content
=> "test"
```

I hope this will help someone! Thanks for the comments!